# Hole on Canon EOS M10 LCD screen?

Tags: canon, lcd

I own a Canon EOS M10 and a friend of mine borrowed and I just have it back today. At first I thought I could trust her, but when I have it back turns out the LCD screen is far more scratched than before, but thank God I use a LCD screen protector. However I noticed some kind of hole punctured on the left side of the screen. I don't know whether or not the hole got to the actual screen because it's on the 'black' part of the LCD (?). Any idea on how to ensure the hole is just on the protector? Thanks before. [image]

Comment: Remove the protector and see if the hole is still on the screen?

Comment: It's kind of hard to remove and I'm afraid it will just do more damage. :'(

Comment: Can you post some pictures?

Comment: What is the point of a screen protector if it damages what it is supposed to be protecting when you remove it to put a fresh one on?

Comment: There, I put up a picture.

Comment: The screen protector is designed to be sacrificial. Remove it and buy another one, that's the whole point of them

Answer (score 1):

Take of the screen protector and inspect the condition of the LCD screen. It is scratched up and probably due for replacement anyway.

In the future the social problem, to the degree it is a problem, can be avoided by not lending out equipment or deciding that cameras are more easily repaired or replaced than friendships.

If the screen is damaged, significant responsibility for that damage lies with the manufacturer and retailer of the screen protector since it has failed to do its job.

Comment: Peeled the screen protector and thank heavens the actual LCD's still intact. Thanks, will keep that one in mind...